# COM 0x8001010E error when invoking from a new thread

Tags: c++, windows, com

I have a c++ DLL that uses an IDispatch interface to invoke methods on a third party DLL. It works if I invoke those methods from the original thread but if a new thread is started (not the one CoCreateInstance was called on) to invoke the method after the it throws a 0x800101E error is thrown. I also tried CoInitialize on the second thread without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 0x8001010E is `RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD` "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.".

You are breaking COM apartment rules and you are attempting to use an interface pointer on a thread that does not belong to apartment the pointer is valid for. To pass interface pointer to another apartment use marshaling.

See [What is COM marshaling and how do I use it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/10/20/10648886.aspx) and [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316), and this [Understanding The COM Single-Threaded Apartment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9506/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment).