# Exception thrown when use await Task.Run() in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, task

I used two Task.Run. In the first one everything works correctly, but in the second an exception is thrown:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD).

I do not understand how to solve it. I would like to understand from the code that the `Task.Run` returns a `TextHighlighter`. What is the right solution?

xaml:

```xaml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="CommandGrid" Margin="25,50,0,50" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel x:Name="CommandStack" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button x:Name="btnFind" Click="btnFind_Click" Content="Find Words" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="32"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txbToFind" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="32" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="BaseGrid" Margin="250,50,50,50" Background="#FFCBF3A6">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="BaseScroll">
            <RichTextBlock x:Name="TextOneRich" Margin="20,20,35,20"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Paste the text here" });
        TextOneRich.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
    }

    private async void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tofind = txbToFind.Text.ToLower();
        string completeText = string.Empty;

        for (int a = 0; a <= TextOneRich.Blocks.Count - 1; a++)
        {
            Paragraph paragraphCurrent = TextOneRich.Blocks[a] as Paragraph;
            for (int b = 0; b <= paragraphCurrent.Inlines.Count - 1; b++)
            {
                completeText += (paragraphCurrent.Inlines[b] as Run).Text;
            }
        }

        List<int> indexList = await Task.Run(async () => await DoStuffAsync(completeText, tofind)); // Works well
        TextHighlighter HighlighterAll = await Task.Run(async () => await CreateHighlighter(indexList, tofind.Length)); // Generate exception

        TextOneRich.TextHighlighters.Clear();
        TextOneRich.TextHighlighters.Add(HighlighterAll);
    }

    private async Task<TextHighlighter> CreateHighlighter(List<int> listaindex, int lenght)
    {
        TextHighlighter Higlighter = new TextHighlighter() { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White), Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 7, 58, 77)) };
        for (int a = 0; a <= listaindex.Count - 1; a++)
        {
            Higlighter.Ranges.Add(new TextRange() { StartIndex = listaindex[a], Length = lenght });
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(Higlighter);
    }

    private async Task<List<int>> DoStuffAsync(string myTxt, string toFind)
    {
        bool thereis = true;
        List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
        string remainingText = string.Empty;
        remainingText = myTxt;
        int progressiveIndex = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while (thereis)
        {
            if (remainingText.ToLower().IndexOf(toFind) != -1)
            {
                indexList.Add(remainingText.ToLower().IndexOf(toFind) + progressiveIndex);
                index = remainingText.ToLower().IndexOf(toFind) + 1;
                progressiveIndex += index;
                remainingText = remainingText.Substring(index, remainingText.Length - index);
            }
            else
            {
                thereis = false;
            }
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(indexList);
    }
}
```

Text to paste: [text](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjedWjxtK_C8sBBdxqEo6Rd17ryX).

Exception screenshot: [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya7Mn.png).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430543/com-0x8001010e-error-when-invoking-from-a-new-thread

Comment: Your `DoStuffAsync` method doesn't appear to do anything that has to be done on the UI thread. `CreateHighligher` does.

Comment: And why is an exception created?

Comment: I correct the code.

Comment: So much is wrong with the code. :( The exception should be reasonably clear: you're executing code in the wrong thread. See marked duplicate for information about that. You _could_ fix the problem by following that advice, but you have a more fundamental problem: the work will just wind up back on the UI thread, blocking it while you do it. The only way around this is to do the work in batches, and allow the UI thread time to refresh periodically. Unfortunately, with no [mcve] here, there's no good way to solve the problem you really have. See marked duplicate for solution to problem you asked

Answer (score 0):

The general problem with your code is that you are using `Task`s for code that performs no kind of asynchronous I/O work. Both `CreateHighlighter` and `DoStuffAsync` are said to be `Task` for absolutely no good reason.
Moreover, since `CreateHighlighter` is working with UI objects, is worse to make that `async` since you aren't in the UI context (due to your usage of `Task.Run`). This is how your code should look like:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ... 
    private async void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        List<int> indexList = await Task.Run(DoStuff(completeText, tofind)); 
        TextHighlighter HighlighterAll = CreateHighlighter(indexList, tofind.Length);
        ...
    }

    private TextHighlighter CreateHighlighter(List<int> listaindex, int lenght)
    {
        ...
        return Higlighter;
    }

    private List<int> DoStuff(string myTxt, string toFind)
    {
        ...
        return indexList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I created Task.Run CreateHighlighter because the cycle in this method blocks the app.

Comment: What I would like to do is to add the range list to the TextHighlighter asynchronously so as not to block the app.

Comment: @Jib58 I am not sure of the correct syntaxis in UWP, but if you want that to be asynchronous you still need to do it aware of the UI thread. Probably with a Dispatcher class

Comment: Is just what I would like to be able to do ... I tried in every way but without result .. any idea?

Comment: @Jib58 It should be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149767/uwp-update-ui-from-task)

Comment: With a short range list it works but, with a longer for example of 40000 indexes freezes .. I would like to make it asyncrono without blocking the app ..

Comment: Is it possible to run the second Tasck.Run (CreateHighlighter) as the first?

Comment: @Jib58 Not really, since as I mentioned, UI objects need to be created in the UI thread. That's why I gave you a link to how to run async actions in the UI context

Comment: But the TextHighlifhter is not part of the UI and so it should be possible ... no? I do not understand this ..